# Date format issue in linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am importing data from excel to SQL table. The date format in excel is 20090109 and after importing the data is stored in 2.00901e+007 this format.

In sql query it is returning date in correct format. but in linq 2.00901e+007 format is not working.

How I can change the 2.00901e+007 to ddMMyyyy?

Comment: How are you importing the data?

Answer (score 0):

You get the correct value. Your problem is Excel cell formatting. Excel thinks that '20090109' is a number and then converts it into exp format: 2.00901e+007.

You can set excel cell format as text:

```
worksheet.get_Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@";
```

Or you can put a ' in front of your number before adding into excel.

If you do not want to format excel cell as text, then convert your sql returned value into DateTime. Set cell number format `"ddMMyyyy"`

Correction:

Sorry for my misunderstanding. I assumed that you import data from SQL to Excel. Seems that you do not convert value you read from Excel into DateTime.

```
string Value = "Value read from Excel";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(Value, "ddMMyyyy", null);
```

You can then use the DateTime value to enter into SQL:

```
dt.ToString("ddMMyyyy")
```

Comment: I think the OP does not want to import INTO excel, but FROM Excel INTO a sql table

Comment: @Serv: You are right. I edited the answer. Thank you for correction.